# mPDF page background property is hiding footer behind background image?

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

I have added this css in the `mpdfstyletables.css` at line 1:

```
@page {
        background: url("abc.jpg") repeat;
}
```

What should I do so that my footer should not be behind the background image?

Answer (score 0):

Use following CSS code to apply a background image to PDF

body {background: url("swril.jpg"); background-image-resize:6;}

This code doesn't hide you header & footer code.

Comment: It does hide footer